# Facebook API GET recent post ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on a little PHP 'script' that will automatically grab the Post ID from the most recent post on a Facebook page.

I have so far got this:

```
$status = $facebook->api("/645017715510822/feed?fields=id&limit=1&access_token=".$token, 'GET');
```

When I run this through my browser as https://graph.facebook.com/645017715510822/feed?fields=id&limit=1&access_token=XXXXXX then it will display the information that I need:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "645017715510822_1484080338478440",
         "created_time": "2014-04-07T12:15:32+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/645017715510822/feed?fields=id&limit=1&access_token=XXXXXX&since=1396872932&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/645017715510822/feed?fields=id&limit=1&access_token=XXXXXX&until=1396872931"
   }
}
```

What I am needing is for it to then grab only the 'id' and possibly print it?
My knowledge of PHP isn't wonderful and I've already tried searching related posts on here, but can't seem to find anything for my exact request, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
if( !empty($status['data']) )
{
   foreach($status["data"] as $s) 
   {
      $id = $s["id"];
   }
}
else
{
   //error
}
```